# Efficient way for multiple database table query using Google Apps Script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc

I'm new in SQL database and Google Apps Script. Currently I have small project using Google Apps Script and connecting to MySql database using JDBC service. The script is currently working fine. However, it will take a lot of time  to return the queries values especially if the script is querying for a multiple tables and multiple query execution. Is there any way to make my code more efficient?

Currently I'm using this code (this is one of sample of my code. Some of the other code I write multiple execution CRUD query from multiple tables:

```
function getdatafromDB(data){
  var errorLog;
  var sqlData = getTableData(forecastSale);
  if(typeof sqlData === "String"){
    errorLog = sqlData;
  } else {
    var dbmsdata = {
    companylist: getTableData(companies),
    dbdata: sqlData,
    };
  }
  return errorLog == null ? dbmsdata : errorLog;
}

function getTableData(tableName){
  var tableData = [];
  var errorLog;
  try {
    var url = "jdbc:mysql://"+dbserver+":"+dbPort+"/"+dbName;
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url,dbUsername,dbPassword);
    var tableQuerydata = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tableName);
    var metaData = tableQuerydata.getMetaData();
    var colnums = metaData.getColumnCount();

    while (tableQuerydata.next()){
      var rowStr = [];
      for (var col=0; col<colnums; col++){
        rowStr[col] = tableQuerydata.getString(col + 1);
      }
      var columnData = rowStr.reduce((a,c,idx) => {
        return {...a,[metaData.getColumnName(idx+1)]:c} 
      },{});
      tableData.push(columnData);   
    }
  } catch (err){
    errorLog = logError(err);
  }
  return errorLog == null ? tableData : errorLog;
}
```